# Create Term (group) in Term store using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: python-3.x, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to create a new term group in the SharePoint Term group using the Microsoft Graph API

Reading term groups via get request works using the following permission in Azure Active Directory: "TermStore.ReadWrite.All - Application - Read and write all term store data.

However creating via post request results in an error 400/403.

Termstore application permission is available in AAD however the documentation doesnt say it is. [Link to MS graph termstore doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/termstore-group-post?view=graph-rest-1.0).

```
termstore_get_groups = (
req.get(
    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{root_site_id}/termStore/groups",
    headers= {"Authorization" : f"Bearer {access_token}", "Host" : "graph.microsoft.com"}
    )
    )

termstore_create_group = (
req.post(
    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{root_site_id}/termStore/groups",
    headers= {"Authorization" : f"Bearer {access_token}"},
    data= {"displayName" : "Test"}
    )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution, You have to add app@sharepoint as a termstore admin

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/466322/azure-ad-application-permission-for-sharepoint-ter.html

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add Content-Type: application/json which is required header along with authorization header.

```
 headers= {"Authorization" : f"Bearer {access_token}" ,.....,'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

as this is required as per
[Create termStore group - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/termstore-group-post?view=graph-rest-1.0)
[image]

This even may happen if user doesn't have sufficient permissions/ privileges for the group under which you are trying to update the term. Please check if the  user needs to have at least a 'contributor' to that group which is parent of the term.